# Django adding item to many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to django thus the question. I've the following Feed object and an User object which have a many-to-many relationship

```
class Feed(Base):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField()
    reader = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Bookmark')

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

The two are related using the Bookmark object.

```
class Bookmark(Base):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

My question is,

1. How do I add a bookmark(or rather feed) to the user?
2. How do I fetch all the feeds the User has bookmarked?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What difficulties you are facing to create and access bookmarks?

Comment: Melissa, I provided a full answer below, tailored to your case. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's start from the beginning.

As you probably know, when you generate M2M rels with Django, you use the `ManyToManyField`. If you do not care about M2M table details, Django will manage it for you. If you want to specify the intermediary table you can use `ManyToManyField.through`. Exactly as you did. I'm going to semplify your model for explanation purposes. Something like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(null=True, unique=True, max_length=255)

class Feed(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reader = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Bookmark')

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Let's start Django interactive shell. I assume you have an empty database.

```
$ django manage.py shell
```

First of all import your models

```
>>> from yourAppName.models import *
```

Now, create some data:

```
>>> from bat.models import *
>>> u1 = User(username = 'foo')
>>> u1.save()
>>> u2 = User(username = 'bar')
>>> u2.save()
>>> User.objects.all() # get Users u1 and u2
<QuerySet [<User: User object>, <User: User object>]>
>>> f1 = Feed(headline = 'How to use M2M in Django')
>>> f1.save()
>>> Feed.objects.all() # get Feed f1
<QuerySet [<Feed: Feed object>]>
```

> 1. How do I add a bookmark (or rather feed) to the user?

In this case, you cannot use `Feed.reader.add(u1)`, you have to use the `Bookmark`'s Manager since you specified that's your intermediary model.

```
>>> b1 = Bookmark(user=u1, feed = f1) # add Feed f1 to User u1
>>> b1.save() # save into database
```

We can also add another bookmark:

```
>>> f2 = Feed(headline = 'Fetching data in Django like a pro!')
>>> f2.save()
>>> b2 = Bookmark(user=u1, feed = f2) # add Feed f2 to User u1
>>> b2.save() # save into database
```

You are done! Now, we can check if everything is fine.

```
>>> brandNewBookMark = Bookmark.objects.all()[0] # get the first bookmark
>>> print(brandNewBookMark.user.username) # it's Foo!
foo
>>> print(brandNewBookMark.feed.headline) # Foo subscribed to f1!
u'How to use M2M in Django'
```

> 2. How do I fetch all the feeds the User has bookmarked?

You can simply leverage the `Feed.reader` field. E.g.,

```
>>> for f in Feed.objects.filter(reader = u1):
...     print(f.headline)
...    
How to use M2M in Django
Fetching data in Django like a pro!
```

That's it! Further info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: @MelissaStewart let me know if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example for your problem

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

For this models, if you want to add memberships, you do this:

```
>>> ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")
>>> paul = Person.objects.create(name="Paul McCartney")
>>> beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Ringo Starr>]>
>>> ringo.group_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: The Beatles>]>
>>> m2 = Membership.objects.create(person=paul, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1960, 8, 1),
...     invite_reason="Wanted to form a band.")
>>> beatles.members.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Ringo Starr>, <Person: Paul McCartney>]>
```

Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships:

```
>>> # The following statements will not work
>>> beatles.members.add(john)
>>> beatles.members.create(name="George Harrison")
>>> beatles.members.set([john, paul, ringo, george])
```

You can see this better in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @MelissaStewart no idea :(

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo that's not a downvote of mine, but I guess someone downvoted because this is just an example, not an answer to the OP question, Besides, it seems a mere copy and paste of the Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).